# how are the global effects of local environmental disasters?

Tags: volcanic-hazard, reference-request, seismic-hazards, natural-disasters

Are there any local environmental catastrophes that affected another places in the world?

There is a huge list of environmental disasters on Wikipedia that I have found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_environmental_disasters

I would really appreciate if there are some academic or non academic references that point out the global effects of local environmental disasters?

Edit: To be more specific, for example, can a catastrophe that occurred in a Latin American country affect the environmental quality (pollution level) in another place in the world (Asia, Africa or another place)?

Let's say that the pollution level increased in USA and resulted in a catastrophe. Could we say that higher level of pollution and catastrophe occurred in USA can cause another catastrophe in somewhere else?

Comment: Are you asking if they are all linked to a certain source?

Comment: @TheVoid yes in some sense. For example, can a disaster in a latin american country could affect the environmental quality in another place (far or close) ?

Comment: You might have to narrow down the question and be more specific to generate a credible answer.

Comment: @TheVoid Thanks for your comment. I tried to be more specific with editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add to Ben MS's answer by mentioning the 2010 eruption of Eyjafjallajökull in Iceland, that shut down air traffic for quite some time.

Another example that comes to mind are tsunamis. The 2004 tsunami in the Indian Ocean mostly affect South East Asia: Indonesia, Thailand, Sri Lanka, and the eastern part of India. But other areas were affected as well, for example in Africa: Somalia, Kenya and the neighbouring Yemen. Here's a map:

[image]

Another example is the Fukushima disaster in Japan, triggered by an earthquake. Some of the radioactive stuff may have ended up in America (although not everyone is convinced of that, and the scary maps you see online are not actually true).

Comment: @optimalcontrol don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the V next to it!

Answer (score 5):

An excellent example of this would be the [Mount Pinatubo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Pinatubo#1991_eruption) eruption in 1991. The [specific nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinian_eruption) of this eruption features massive amounts of aerosols and ash put into the atmosphere. When Mount Pinatubo erupted, the amount of dust and ash it injected into the atmosphere was responsible for a worldwide reduction in temperature of 0.5–0.6 °C in the northern hemisphere over the next year, as well as a massive increase in ozone depletion.